# run jmeter in non gui mode, sending parameters for a groovy script, howto?

Tags: jmeter

My testplan uses a JSR223 PreProcessor, which invokes a .groovy script with a parameter.
In GUI mode this parameter can be set in section "Parameters to be passed to script".

How can I define/set the value (the parameter) when jmeter runs in non-gui mode?
Can't find anything on that in the documentation!

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? If ok you should accept it and upvote so that others can trust it ?

Answer (score 0):

It is the same plan that run in GUI and NON GUI mode.
So you can use the same mechanism.

To pass the value from command line:

> -JpropName=value

To get it, use [__P](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function:

> ${__P(propName)}